# Swift - BLE AllowDuplicatesKey behavior

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question for people who have knowledge of BLE.

I have 2 ble devices (they are the same, so same primary service)
When I start the scan with the option `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey = false` and I put the 2 devices in advertisment, there is only one which is discovered. Why is the second one not discovered?

On what basis the parameter `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`? Does it only based on the primary service to decide that a device is duplicate, or it is based on the device identifier (mac address)?

For the moment, according to my tests, I have the impression which is based only on the primary service, am I right?

If this is the case I think it is an error which is not based on the identifier (mac address) of the peripheral to decide if it is duplicate

**EDIT**

Code for start scanning is very straightforward:

```
        let options = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false] 
        let devicesUUID = devices.compactMap { $0?.cbUUID }
        
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: devicesUUID, options: options)
```

My delegate:

```
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        logger?.log(emoji: "️", message: "Found \(getPeripheralName(from: peripheral)) - \(peripheral.identifier)")
    }
```

Comment: The allow duplicates key causes multiple calls to `didDiscover` for the same device (`identifier`). If you have two peripherals advertising the same service and that is the service you are scanning for and you have allow duplicates false then you should get two `didDiscover` calls. If you have allow duplicates true then you should get a series of  `didDiscover` calls for the two peripherals (two different identifiers).

Comment: If you are only seeing one device then either the second one isn't advertising, it isn't advertising the service you think it is, the peripherals are "dodgy and have the same MAC address or you have a problem with your code. Show your code.

Comment: Look at my edit, the code is very basic, the problem is that the 2 are in advertisement and I'm sure.
I will add a precision. A device share in ibeacon too.
So when he enters a advertisement and shares the beacon for 10 seconds, it wakes up my application and I start the scan, at the same time I take advantage that the application is awake to put the second device in advertisement (he does not have ibeacon) and the second device is not discovered in the scan

Comment: What is  `devices.compactMap { $0?.cbUUID }` for? What is `devices`? Try scanning for `nil` to discover all advertising devices and then you can confirm that the devices are advertising. You can also use the Light Blue app from the store to see what services your devices are advertising.

Comment: I expect your second device is having trouble (which would match exactly the symptom you're describing). Why do you believe it's advertising? What scanner tool are you using other than your app? I recommend using nRF Connect or LiteBlue to do the scanning and see if the device is really working. Also check its advertising interval. If it isn't one of the recommended Apple intervals (they're very precise), it can take a long time to discover.

Comment: As Paulw11 says, I except the line "let devicesUUID = devices.compactMap { $0?.cbUUID }" is not doing what you expect.